# How to save objects in django directly to data base?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, error-handling, insert

I'm using django 1.11 python 3.5 and postgresql on ubuntu 16.

I'm trying to build something like sports event website.

It's consist of 2 parts:

1. Django app.
2. Python script that inserting new objects to django database with events. Code for inserting:

   1. get information about max primary key, pk = z

   INSERT INTO events_event VALUES pk = z, event_name = name ....

In this part, everything works correctly.

**But, when I trying to save objects from django admin, I see an error:**

```
IntegrityError at /admin/events/event/add/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "events_event_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(7) already exists.
```

What is an issue with this problem?

How should I organize my code so I can save a lot of objects to a database?

Comment: Why aren't you using django's ORM?

Comment: I divided a project into 2 parts and creating events out of django app. So I can't use django ORM. 
Do you mean that I should do everything in django app with no outside python script?

Comment: Google for `django standalone script` there are bunch of examples how to use django's env in other python scripts.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

And also I would suggest writing management command for this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: thank's think it will help.